# Is it possible to insert values from one table into another AND update field values in same query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables. One table is meant to serve as a transaction history and the other is a log of member details. When a report is run, I want to move pieces of the member details into the transaction history but ALSO update some field records which would not otherwise exist.

Is it possible to select all records which meet a specific criteria, insert only pieces of the matching row into another table AND update other fields in a single query?

For example:

In table 2, i have member name, date registered, and memberid. I want to move the above records into table 1 but also update the field (status) equal to 'processed'.

Note: I am also using php and pdo to connect to a mysql database.

Is this possible within a single query?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a single query?  Why not wrap two queries in a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)?

Comment: good point - the more im thinking about, the more useless the single query seems...

Comment: Two readable, efficient queries are better than one big convoluted query any day of the week.  Both from a semantic and a performance standpoint.  Don't get caught in the trap of less is always better (there are tradeoffs of course, but it's not a universal truth)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much consideration - I decided to use ircmaxell's advice and simply run multiple queries. It ends up not only making things easier but allows me to customize my sorting much easier.

As he said above, "Don't get caught in the trap of less is always better"

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify whether the rows you want to update are the same as the ones you are inserting. I am assuming they are:

```
insert into table1
(member_name, date_registered, memberid, status)
select member_name, date_registered, memberid, 'processed'
from table2
where SomeField = MyCriteria
```

Comment: issue is, im using prepared statements and pdo so when i try to run the code with ..." select member_name, date_registered, memberid, SET status=?..." it gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
SELECT *, "processed" INTO table2 FROM table1
```

You will have to adapt based on the table structures, perhaps even write out all the fields:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, "processed" INTO table2 FROM table1
```

Of note, this assumes you want to write into table 2 *including* the processed variable (Might I suggest a boolean?) if you want the "Processed" in the other table it will get more complicated.

**Edit:** Apparently mysql doesn't support select into so...

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT field1, field2, field3, "processed" FROM table1
```

Redfilters code works

Comment: @JV - main issue is the prepared statement clause, I may simply run two queries if need be because i have to run the statement above in a loop based on the result returned regardless (multiple inserts will happen here).